# vga graphic mode has meny noise

Tags: vga

I want to erase noise.
I use VirtualBox and refer this website. 
http://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware

This picture is result:
[image]

```
// unlock CRTC registers 
outb_p(0x3, 0x3d4);
      outb_p(inb_p(0x3d5) | 0x80, 0x3d5);
      outb_p(0x11, 0x3d4);
      outb_p(inb_p(0x3d5) & ~0x80, 0x3d5);

outb_p(0x10, 0x3c0); outb_p(0x01, 0x3c1);  // mode control
outb_p(0x11, 0x3c0); outb_p(0x00, 0x3c1);  // overscan register
outb_p(0x12, 0x3c0); outb_p(0x0f, 0x3c1);  // color plane enable
outb_p(0x13, 0x3c0); outb_p(0x00, 0x3c1);  // horizontal plane enable
outb_p(0x14, 0x3c0); outb_p(0x00, 0x3c1);  // color select
outb_p(0xe3, 0x3c2); // misc out register
outb_p(0x01, 0x3c4); outb_p(0x01, 0x3c5);  // clock mode register
outb_p(0x03, 0x3c4); outb_p(0x00, 0x3c5);  // character select
outb_p(0x04, 0x3c4); outb_p(0x02, 0x3c5);  // memory mode register
outb_p(0x05, 0x3ce); outb_p(0x00, 0x3cf);  // mode register
outb_p(0x06, 0x3ce); outb_p(0x05, 0x3cf);  // misc register
outb_p(0x00, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x5f, 0x3d5);  // horizontal total
outb_p(0x01, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x4f, 0x3d5);  // horizontal display enable end
outb_p(0x02, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x50, 0x3d5);  // horizontal blank start
outb_p(0x03, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x82, 0x3d5);  // horizontal blank end
outb_p(0x04, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x54, 0x3d5);  // horizontal retrace start
outb_p(0x05, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x80, 0x3d5);  // horizontal retrace end
outb_p(0x06, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x0b, 0x3d5);  // vertical total
outb_p(0x07, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x3e, 0x3d5);  // overflow register
outb_p(0x08, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x00, 0x3d5);  // preset row scan
outb_p(0x09, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x40, 0x3d5);  // max scan line
outb_p(0x10, 0x3d4); outb_p(0xea, 0x3d5);  // vertical retrace start
outb_p(0x11, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x8c, 0x3d5);  // vertical retrace end
outb_p(0x12, 0x3d4); outb_p(0xdf, 0x3d5);  // vertical display enable end
outb_p(0x13, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x28, 0x3d5);  // logical width
outb_p(0x14, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x00, 0x3d5);  // underline location
outb_p(0x15, 0x3d4); outb_p(0xe7, 0x3d5);  // vertical blank start
outb_p(0x16, 0x3d4); outb_p(0x04, 0x3d5);  // vertical blank end
outb_p(0x17, 0x3d4); outb_p(0xe3, 0x3d5);  // mode control
```

Comment: I find it unclear what you expected the result to look like. Also, could you explain what you're attempting to do with those VGA register writes (i.e. what kind of mode are you attempting to set)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.    I don't explain in detail.  VGA is very very difficult.   I have a little understanding.    0x??→insert→result

Comment: Well, I'm assuming you're doing all those register writes for a reason, otherwise you could just set a standard mode (like mode 0x13) and be done with it. What resolution, pixel format and memory layout are you attempting to set?